# How do I change the unattended account password automatically while changing it in AD level?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have configured the PerformancePoint service with an unattended account which is an [AD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) user account. If I change the password of this account in [Active Directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory), how do I configure PerformancePoint service with automatically refreshing with a new password?

Answer (score 0):

You should look in the Managed accounts.

It is a way of storing and handling the user in SharePoint, in compliance with your AD.

> To simplify password management, the automatic password change feature
>   enables you to update and deploy passwords without having to perform
>   manual password update tasks across multiple accounts, services, and
>   web applications. You can configure the automatic password change
>   feature to determine whether a password is about to expire and reset
>   the password using a long, cryptographically-strong random string. To
>   implement the automatic password change feature, you have to configure
>   managed accounts.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724278(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724278%28v=office.15%29.aspx)